# Is there a mathematical equivalent of this function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I hacked together a function for a conversion between to different scales of numbers and I'm just wondering if there is a mathematical equation that this can be represented by.  Or even just a better way of writing this function.

I have an audio device that returns the decibel level of a source and returns it as a number between 0 and 144.  That scale represents 145 values ranging between -60db and +12db with intervals every .5db.

The best way I could come up with was maping -60 through +12 to a `list dbAry` and and choose an index based on the value returned from the audio device.

```
def convert(self, value):
    dbAry = []
    a = -60
    while a != 12.5:
        dbAry.append(a)
        a+=0.5

    return dbAry[int(value)]
```

EDIT: Python 2.7 by the way.

Comment: Omg. `return .5*value-60`

Comment: @SergeSeredenko that wouldn't work. Try 145

Comment: @TheProgrammerG 145 is invalid according to the question

Comment: @SergeSeredenko oh yeah. My bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
ans = original_number / 2 - 60
```

This converts the original_number to the format you need.

Test:

```
110 / 2 - 60 = -5
144 / 2 - 60 = 12
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.  When I run 110 through this it returns -60.  The value I would be looking for is -5.  However, I'm beginning to believe that there might not be a mathematical solution for this. But I'm not a mathematician!

Comment: @Nick That's not right. Try calculating it again. You must have made a mistake.

Comment: Well I see the answer has changed, I'll try this then. EDIT: And that does work for me, thanks a lot!